# sipMalloc is undefined when using to allocate buffers

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, python-sip

Hi all I am developing an application on QT, and I need to run Python scripts from my application. I am trying to allocate some memory using sipMalloc function. Which is provided in python-SIP. I am using PyQt 4 and python v2.7.

I am importing sip.so im my script thich is present in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

**NameError: name 'sipMalloc' is not defined**

if there is any other alternative to allocate memory in python script w.r.t. QT Application plz share. Thanks

******SOLVED******
I dropped the idea of using SIP. Instead I am using SWIG with python for creating library of exported functions. And SWIG also provides option to allocate memory using malloc, which can be used directly in Python Scripts. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14804084/1329652

Comment: `sipMalloc` is a C function. It's not callable from Python. Python does memory allocation automatically. Please let us know what exactly are you trying to do? Show some python code where the supposed `sipMalloc`'s result is passed to. Most likely you don't need anything like that, or you should be allocating the memory in the wrapper code, not from Python.

Comment: Thanks bro. My problem is solved now

Comment: Then please delete your question. In its current state, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

One more problem I faces with SIP was exporting existing structures. SIP was not able to recognize when I used typedef and bit fields in the structures. But with SWIG, I exported all the structures by adding in .i file to the python scripts.