# Error in saving an instance of django model. But the snippet works, if not saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This is my django views code snippet:

```
if (calltype == 'save'):
        bill_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('bill_details'))
        Invoice=salesInvoice()
        customerkey = request.POST.get('customer')
        Invoice.customer_key = Customer.object.get(key__iexact=customerkey)
        Invoice.total = request.POST.get('total')
        Invoice.grand_discount = request.POST.get('grand_discount')
        Invoice.amount_paid = request.POST.get('amount_paid')
        #Invoice.save()

        #saving the salesLineItem and linking them with foreign key to invoice
        for data in bill_data:
            LineItem = salesLineItem()
            #LineItem.invoice_no = salesInvoice
            itemcode=data['itemCode']
            LineItem.name = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).name
            LineItem.unit = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).unit
            LineItem.batch = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).batch
            LineItem.discount1 = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).discount1
            LineItem.discount2 = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).discount2
            LineItem.quantity = int(data['itemQuantity'])
            LineItem.free = int(data['itemFree'])
            LineItem.mrp = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).mrp
            LineItem.selling_price = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).selling_price
            LineItem.vat_type = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).vat_type
            LineItem.vat_percent = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).vat_percent
            #LineItem.save()
        #this part is just for checking
        response_data['name'] = Product.object.get(key__iexact=itemcode).name
```

Do note that I've commented out the lines used to save the invoice and lineitem. Once I un-comment these lines, the error i get is:

```
name 'Invoice' is not defined
```

I also overrode the save method of the django model (for the salesInvoice model). Following is its code (in django models file) and in the commented line I've a small explanation of what that does:

```
#the save method is overriden to give unique invoice ids, slug and customer_name
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    today = dt.date.today()
    today_string = today.strftime('%y%m%d')
    next_invoice_number = '01'
    last_invoice = Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id__startswith=today_string).order_by('invoice_id').last()
    if last_invoice:
        last_invoice_number = int(last_invoice.invoice_id[6:])
        next_invoice_number = '{0:03d}'.format(last_invoice_number + 1)
    self.invoice_id = today_string + next_invoice_number
    if not self.id:
        self.slug=slugify(self.invoice_id)
        customer_name = Customer.object.get(key__iexact=customer_key).name
        address = Customer.object.get(key__iexact=customer_key).address
    super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I dont understand where's the error.
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT 1 - Adding the traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Ganguly PC\Desktop\DjangoStudy\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,  *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ganguly PC\Desktop\DjangoStudy\billinv\billbrain\views.py" in salesinvoice
  173.          Invoice.save()
File "C:\Users\Ganguly PC\Desktop\DjangoStudy\billinv\billbrain\models.py"   in save
  189.      last_invoice =         Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id__startswith=today_string).order_by('invoice_id').last()

Exception Type: NameError at /master/salesinvoice/
Exception Value: name 'Invoice' is not defined
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
amount_paid = '0.00'
customer = 'fr'
csrfmiddlewaretoken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
bill_details = '[{"itemCode":"rev","itemQuantity":"5","itemFree":"0"}]'
grand_discount = '0.00'
total = '435.00'
calltype = 'save'
```

Comment: You need to learn how to read the stacktrace. Can you edit your question to post the full stacktrace please?

Comment: Well Shang, sure. I'm editing my question with the stacktrace. But is this not called traceback in HTML-Python (Django) & stacktrace in java/c ??

Comment: I might be wrong on the terminology, thanks for the correction. But I'm more interested in helping people on their problem.

Comment: @Shang, thanks a lot :) Really appreciate you helping me out!! I just pointed out to help others - if they see this question - ever !!

Comment: Is the error because of the fact that my databse (of inovices) is blank and the "filter" method to trace the last invoice fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious in your traceback. Line `173` calls `Invoice.save()` then it goes to the `save()` method you overrode. Then Line `189` shows up and tells you the closest place where the error occurs: You were doing:

```
last_invoice = Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id__startswith=today_string).order_by('invoice_id').last()
```

But `Invoice` is not defined. It's more of a python question than a django question. You need to have the class name defined first then use it. In views you did `import Invoice` but here you can't, but you could use `type(self)` to refer to the instance. So do:

```
last_invoice = type(self).objects.filter(invoice_id__startswith=today_string).order_by('invoice_id').last()
```

Comment: I suggest you learn some python basics before jumping into django, it will save you a lot of time asking these basic questions in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined

Comment: Thanks a lot Shang!! Well that was a very stupid mistake! Surely I'm learning python alongside (I went through python 101 & 102), but you see I'm a non tech guy planning on a startup and I dont have a lot of time :(.