# "NameError: name 'answer' is not defined" PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm and gives me this error whenever I try to run the code: NameError: name 'answer' is not defined. Below is the problematic code.

```
array = []
while integer:
    integer, value = divmod(integer, (int(target_system.get())))
    array.append(VA2SY[value])
    global answer
    answer = (''.join(reversed(array)))

print(end)
messagebox.showinfo("Eredmény:", answer)
```

Comment: My research has led me to believe that this is a bug in PyCharm but I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe it's Pycharm way to make sure that the users can't use global variables :)

Comment: What happens if you comment out `global answer`?

Comment: What is the initial value of `integer`?  If it's zero (or other 'falsy' value), the loop will never execute, and therefore no value ever gets assigned to `answer`.

Comment: The "answer" variable being global doesn't make any difference, it's just a leftover from previous tries, if I leave it as a "normal" variable then I get the same error. And i'm sure this is the code that causes the problem.

Comment: You should ask your question more precisely... You can also get such a NameError if you use a class before you defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of how to use a global variable in python.

#### Example:

If you want to use *global_answer* in *somefunc*, you need to tell python that *global_answer* is a global variable.

```
def somefunc():
    # mark global_answer as global variable
    global global_answer
    while global_answer is "global":
        global_answer = "Will show"
        # not_global is a local variable
        not_global = "Will not show"


# Declare variable
global_answer = "global"
not_global = "not global"
somefunc()
print("Global:", global_answer)
print("Not Global:", not_global)
```

#### Error Reproduction

I achieve the same error message with that code:

```
def somefunc():
    while global_answer is "global":
        global global_answer          # Line moved
        global_answer = "Will show"


# Declare variable
global_answer = "global"
somefunc()
```

#### Possible Solution

Move your code line `global answer` to the first line of your method.

Check if you defined all your classes before you use them, else you can also end up with a NameError. [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

The error might be outside of the code you provided. Where do you declare the global variable answer?

Comment: The "answer" variable being global doesn't make any difference, it's just a leftover from previous tries, if I leave it as a "normal" variable then I get the same error. And i'm sure this is the code that causes the problem.