# NameError in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
xx = str(23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44])

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>  
    xx = str(23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44])  
NameError: name 'Jun' is not defined
```

I am using Python 3 in Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: Unless you are using some sort of `Date` object, you should probably place `23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44]` in between quotes: `'23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44]'`, and not use `str`

Comment: Not a good dupe @its_vinayak

Comment: That's not how you define a string. You use quotes. You might as well do it, since you're writing out the literal yourself. :|

Answer (score 2):

Your code just so happens to work in the weirdest of ways :)

This (`xx = str(23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44])`) is interpreted as this:

```py
xx = str(23 - Jun - 2019[8:41:44])
```

It's expecting to get 23 minus `Jun` (a variable) and then get a slice out of 2019.
Because it is working left to right, it gets to 23, sees that it's right, continues on to `Jun`, and tries to find a variable called `Jun`.

Because it couldn't find it, it gave a `NameError`.

What you were probably trying to do is this:

```py
xx = "23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44]"
```

Python's `str` can take anything, including numbers, and turns them into something you can output using something like `print()`. By putting them in a literal, you can make it show what is *literal* ly there.

Answer (score 1):

It is interpreting `-` as subtraction and `Jun` as a variable.

You might like to do

```
xx = "23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44]"
```

if you intended xx to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unfortunately. To declare string use double quotes. I would also recommend `datetime` built-in module if you want to work with date and time.

```py
xx = "23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44]"
```

Answer (score -1):

1). Here you are converting `23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44]` into a string by `str()`. While conversion `str()` is treating `Jun` as a `variable`.

2). And if removing the `Jun` then also the remaining portion is the invalid syntax for PYTHON.

3). USE `" "` When you have this type of situation. AND use the `datetime` module instead of `[8:41:44]`.

```
xx = "23-Jun-2019 [8:41:44]"
```