# I keep having a error when running the script. It keeps sending "name input_file is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a python def to unzip a few .gz files within a folder. I know that the main script works if it is not in the def. The script I have created is similar to others I have done but this one give me the error

> File "unzip.py", line 24, in 
>       decompressed_files(input_folder)
>   NameError: name 'input_folder' is not defined

I copied the script below so someone can help me to see where the error is. I haven't done any BioInformatics for the last couple of years and I am a bit rusty.

```
import glob
import sys
import os
import argparse
import subprocess
import gzip

def decompressed_files(input_folder):
    print ('starting decompressed_files')

    output_folder=input_folder + '/fasta_files'
    if os.path.exists(output_folder):
        print ('folder already exists')
    else:
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    for f in input_folder:
        fastqs=glob.glob(input_folder + '/*.fastq.gz')
        cmd =[gunzip, -k, fastqs, output_folder]
        my_file=subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        my_file.wait

print ('The programme has finished doing its job')
decompressed_files(input_folder)
```

This is done for python 2.7, I know that is old but it is the one that it is installed in my work server.

Comment: When you call `decompressed_files(input_folder)`, there is no variable `input_folder` defined. Where do you expect that to get a value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14804084/11301900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why when you call `decompressed_files(input_folder)` in the last line, you didn't define `input_folder` before. you should do it like this :

```
input_folder = 'C:/Some Address/'
decompressed_files(input_folder)
```