# User input inside function

Tags: python

Why the users input give me error under print ?

```
def num(n):
    sum = n * 5
    print("Amount of n is:", sum)
    user = float(input("Specify any number: "))

num(user)

NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

but why it works under def?I would like to know the logic behind it?

```
def num(n):
    sum = n * 5
    print("Amount of n is:", sum)
user = float(input("Specify any number: "))

num(user)
```

The resut is:

```
Specify any number: 10
Amount of n is: 50.0
```

Comment: Because user variable was in-scope of the function in the latter case;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

Indentation in Python matters, and affects how variables are scoped.

In the first example you posted, `user` is defined inside the scope of the `num` function (inside the indented block under the `def`), so it only exists inside that function.  Furthermore, it doesn't exist until the function is called, so when you call `num(user)`, you're trying to pass `num` a value that doesn't exist.

In the second example, you define `user` outside the function (at the module scope, with no indentation), so it's available to the subsequent line of code at the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

The output shows an error beacuse you are trying to access a local variable "user" in a global scope whereas the local variable only works inside the function. When you declare a variable inside the function's body, we call it as a local variable.

Answer (score -1):

@Samwise answered your question in a clear way.
But if you definetly wanted to take the input with in the function just do this

```
user = 1           # just for a variable need to pass into function
def num(n):
    global user
    n = float(input("Specify any number: "))
    sum = n * 5
    print("Amount of n is:", sum)
    

num(user)
```