# Why isn't the except NameError picking up the name error on my code?

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I'm trying to have a user input an integer, while trying to catch errors if they put in floaters or strings. Any help would be awesome guys!!

```
try:
    user_input = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a whole number with no decimal points")
except NameError:
    print("user_input not defined")
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP is using Python 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: Hey buddy! Thanks for the response

Comment: @JimmyCarlos As I wrote, in python 3 there is no way for `NameError` to be raised by this code (assuming `int`, `input` or `print` were not removed from scope, of course)

Comment: I'm using python 3.7

Comment: @Phoenix So you are using other code which you didn't show us. There is no way for the code you provided to raise `NameError` in Python 3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NameError is called when you try to access a variable not declared yet. But in this code, you will always create user_input, so the try block can't go to the nameerror block.

Comment: If OP is using Python 2 then `NameError` is raised (and caught, so the question is still not clear either way) if a non-existing variable name is entered when `input` is called.