# Recursive class typing in python

Tags: python, typing

I'm looking for typing a class with recursive field

I try the following code:

```py
class Heh:
  child_hehs: list[Heh]
```

but i got following error

> NameError: name 'Heh' is not defined

so I try another code:

```py
class MetaHeh(Heh):
  pass

class Heh:
  child_hehs: list[MetaHeh]
```

and i got following error again:

> NameError: name 'Heh' is not defined

How can i implement this code with typing?

Comment: Either use a string or import the future behaviour; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181507/3001761 for the former, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533148/3001761.

Comment: While above questions are related - this is different scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the name of the recursive type in its declaration. For example:

```
class Heh:
  child_hehs: list['Heh']
```

---

If you can use python 3.7.0b1 and above you can use [Postponed Evaluation of Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/).

```
from __future__ import annotations 
class Heh:     
    child_hehs: list[Heh]
```

This feature is expected to become part of the language in python 3.10 (in other words, without __future__ import).

Comment: Could also use annotations: ```from __future__ import annotations```
```class Heh:
    child_hehs: list[Heh]```

Comment: Nice feature :-)