# Error message 'NameError: name 'filename' is not defined' when using .Create()

Tags: python

When I try the following code on Python notebook I get the error message `'NameError: name 'filename' is not defined'`.

Code:

```
import gdal 
import ogr

ras_ds = gdal.Open('D:/qgisImages/raster1.tiff') 
vec_ds = gdal.Open('D:/qgisImages/vector1.tiff')

lyr = vec_ds.GetLayer()

geot = ras_ds.GetGeoTransform()

import peewee
from peewee import *

drv_tiff = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff") 
chn_ras_ds = drv_tiff.Create(filename, ras_ds.RasterXSize, ras_ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
chn_ras_ds.SetGeoTransform(geot)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

> 'NameError: name 'filename' is not defined'

means your python interpreter didnt find any variable in the code with the name `filename`

Comment: Hello, I am trying to follow the procedures mentioned on the following page  : https://towardsdatascience.com/use-python-to-convert-polygons-to-raster-with-gdal-rasterizelayer-b0de1ec3267. Is there a missing step please? Thank you for your reply