# As you can see for discord.py to listen to other bot the class need to be created and change the client = UnfilteredBot but it is showing me error

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
import os


TOKEN = 'OTUyNDkzMDk4Mjg0NTExMjQy.GSl3Un.HHDKACqLqxuM02q4Yu0eyZGfPQlgJIKhDhmq9U'

bot = UnfilteredBot(command_prefix='?')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
 print('Logged in as')
 print(bot.user.name)
 print(bot.user.id)
 print('------')


 @bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
  """Says world"""
  await ctx.send("world")


@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, left : int, right : int):
"""Adds two numbers together."""
await ctx.send(left + right)

@bot.command()
async def shutdown(ctx):
 await ctx.send("shutting down")
 os.system("shutdown -h now")
 

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/Desktop/app,py", line 8, in

bot = UnfilteredBot(command_prefix='?', description=description)

NameError: name 'UnfilteredBot' is not defined

These are the changes that I did in bot.py of discord bot

```
class UnfilteredBot(commands.Bot):

    async def process_commands(self, message):
        ctx = await self.get_context(message)
        await self.invoke(ctx)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined) answer your question?

Comment: ⚠️ Warning
You shouldn't share any credential online. Please regenerate your bot token, otherwise anyone will have access to your bot.

Comment: Actually, both programs are separate and I am importing my bot.py which is one of the Discord modules. So will my main program read that class if it is in another program?

Comment: You need to overwrite `__all__`. But you shouldn't do this inside of discord's source code anyway. Define it in your own code. (Why do you need to overwrite this anyway?)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still a novice in programming and my friend has taken his project on which I am helping him. I would like to thank all who helped me.