# NameError: name 'inp_en_idx' is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, translation

I have the following translation code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=300, hidden_size=256, num_layers=2) 
attn = nn.Linear(256, 10) 
fc = nn.Linear(10 * 2, 300)

input_en = torch.tensor(inp_en_idx) 
hidden = lstm(input_en)[0]
attn_weights = attn(hidden[-1]) 
context = attn_weights.softmax(dim=1).unsqueeze(1).expand_as(hidden)
context = context * hidden 
context = context.sum(dim=1)
out = fc(context)
```

Upon running it throws this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d484f124dd49> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 fc = nn.Linear(10 * 2, 300)
      6 
----> 7 input_en = torch.tensor(inp_en_idx)
      8 hidden = lstm(input_en)[0]
      9 attn_weights = attn(hidden[-1])

NameError: name 'inp_en_idx' is not defined
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags. (This is likely why your question went under the radar.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)