# Python function invoked before definition

Tags: python, interpreter

I am confused about the below given code in Python where a function has been called before its definition. Is it possible? Is it because the function does not return a value?

```
from Circle import Circle

def main():
    myCircle = Circle()
    n = 5
    printAreas(myCircle, n) #The function is called here

def printAreas(c, times):
    xxxx
    xxxx

main()
```

Comment: What makes you think the function is called before its definition?

Comment: It is not. It is called when main is called, which is at the very end of the program.

Comment: Try to move the *call* to `main` *before* the definition of `printAreas`, as in: `main()<NEWLINE>def printAreas(...): ...`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758188/make-function-definition-in-a-python-file-order-independant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens in your program:

1. `main` is defined, with a reference to `printAreas` in its body—note, this is just a reference, not a call
2. `printAreas` is defined
3. `main` is invoked
4. `main` calls `printAreas`.

So all is good—you are allowed to reference any names you want at any time you want, as long as you ensure these names will have been defined (bound to a value) by the time the code containing the reference is executed:

```
def foo():
    print bar  # reference to as-of-yet non-existent bar

# calling foo here would be an error

bar = 3

foo()  # prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Python will first parse your file, register all function, variables, etc into the global namespace. It will **then** call the `main` function, which will then call `printAreas`. At the time, both functions are in your script namespace, and hence perfectly accessible.

The thing that is confusing you is just the reading order.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `main` at the end of your program. This allows the interpreter to load up all your functions and then start your `main` function.