# Name Error in python

Tags: python

I am getting  the following Name Error in my python program though I declared the function before it is used.

Here is my program:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = None


def insert_at(leaf, value):
    #some code here....


def insert(self,value):
    #some code here....
    insert_at(self.root, value)


def main():
    #some code here
    insert(10)
    #some code here
```

Here is my error:

```
File "programs/binary_tree.py", line 38, in insert
insert_at(self.root, value)
NameError: name 'insert_at' is not defined
```

I did go through the following questions before asking this question, but couldn't understand why I am getting the error.

[Make function definition in a python file order independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758188/make-function-definition-in-a-python-file-order-independant)
and
[Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: @vaultah : Thanks...missed that question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like those are methods in a class. You need the following changes:

```
def insert_at(self, leaf, value): # add self
```

```
self.insert_at(self.root, value) # add self
```

Comment: Lets say I recusrively call insert_at() inside insert_at().. Should i still use self? i.e,  inside insert_at(), should i call it again by self.insert_at()  or just insert_at().   I tried both and they are working...Didnt understand the difference though.

Comment: Yes, still use `self`.