# Position of defining a function

Tags: python, function

Is it necessary to define a function on the top of a code or can we define it in the middle also (i.e in the `__main__` segment)? Like we define a function in the middle will it result in error during execution and flow of control?

Comment: You can define a function almost anywhere in the code.  But be sure to define it **before** you call it.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should be really easy to try. BTW, style is another consideration, but separate to functionality.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: You can even define functions inside functions, there are many use cases where that's a useful thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in Python anywhere you want.  **However**, it won't be defined, and therefore callable, until the function definition is executed.

If you're familiar with many other languages this feels odd, as it seems that most compilers/interpreters will identify functions anywhere in your code *before* execution and they will be available anywhere in your code.  Python interpreters do **not** do that.

The following 2 code samples are both syntactically correct, but the second will fail because hello() isn't defined until *after* it is called:

Example 1 (works!):

```
def hello():
    print('Hello World')

hello()
```

Example 2 (fails! - name 'hello' is not defined):

```
hello()

def hello():
    print('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look to Python's definition.

Python is an **interpreted** high-level general-purpose programming language. (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language))

The *interpreted* is the key. We can think as if python executes the code line by line before checking the whole file. (It is a bad analogy, but for sake of this problem let's think it is true)

Now there can be many scenarios:

### Running a function after declaration

```
foo()

def foo():
    print("foo")
```

This would fail

### Running a function before declaration

```
def foo():
    print("foo")

foo()
```

this would succeed

### Calling a function inside a function

```
def foo():
   print("foo")

def bar():
   foo()

bar()
```

or

```
def bar():
   foo()

def foo():
   print("foo")
bar()
```

These would succeed. Please notice in second example `foo` declared after `bar`. But still runs. See: [Make function definition in a python file order independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758188/make-function-definition-in-a-python-file-order-independent)

```
def foo():
   print("foo")

bar()

def bar():
   foo()
```

This would fail

Comment: why the second example still runs in which foo is declared after bar ?

Comment: It is about declaration before execution. You see in the second example we used `foo` inside the `bar`, and before using `bar` we declared the `foo`. Nothing was executed before it's declaration.